# "Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ^^S (U+0013)" while citing an article

Tags: unicode

I am getting the error `Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ^^S (U+0013)` while citing an article in overleaf. The minimal code and the bibliography are provided underneath:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\cite{Malik2021NewEO}

\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

the ref.bib file:

```
@article{Malik2021NewEO,
  title={New equation of state involving Bos…Einstein condensate of antikaon for supernova and neutron star merger simulations},
  author={Tuhin Malik and Sarmistha Banik and Debades Bandyopadhyay},
  journal={European Physical Journal-special Topics},
  year={2021},
  pages={1-6}
}
```

Comment: There's a funky character in the title of you cited article. Should read "Bose-Einstein condensate", I suppose. Just make it a regular e and a hyphen.

Comment: Usually for such bugs, re-typing the whole content "by hand" will fix it, if not a little tedious.